# MS Access collection object value is being overwritten

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a global collection object in a form that I am using to store IDs.

```
Dim newCollection As New Collection
```

When a user hits a btn

```
Private Sub btn_Click()
Dim key As Variant
    newCollection.ADD Me.ID, CStr(ID)

    For Each key In newCollection
        Debug.Print key 
    Next key
End Sub
```

When a user is at ID 1 in the forms and  presses the button above I get the expected `1` returned on my immediate window

But when A user moves to another record in the form let's say from ID 1 to 2 using the forms navigation button

For Some reason the  `Debug.Print key` returns

```
2
2
```

rather than the expected

```
1
2
```

For Some reason the key is not overwritten but the value is. What I mean is that

On my immediate console:

```
?newCollection(1)
```

returns 2

And

```
?newCollection(2)
```

also returns 2

I don't know why this is happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this ...

```vba
newCollection.ADD Me.ID, CStr(ID)
```

to this ...

```vba
newCollection.ADD Me.ID.Value, CStr(ID)
```

In the first case, you're adding a field object.  So when you later `Debug.Print key`, you're printing the current value of that field.  (That may make more sense if you do `Debug.Print TypeName(key)` temporarily.)

You need to add the field's value instead of the field itself.